# Weight Paint is streching

Tags: vertices, faces, weight-painting, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

I am a beginner in blender and i am using blender 3.0.0 I stretched a plane and subdivided it but when i weight paint it. The weight paint is also stretching. Is there any way so that i can stop weight paint from stretching. Please help me out with your knowledge.[image]
Here's the link of the Blender file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11eB4Ydo14Hrc4Jsitse03lQxfyYIvGEG/view?usp=sharing Blender file link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have "Plane" with size of 690 MB? :-)

The problem is that you have uneven scale. Apply scale at first - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ⇾ **Scale**

[image]

Comment: Even i am wondering why the file size is 690 MB

Comment: you have 4 millions vertices, do you need so many vertices?

Comment: I dont know. At first i was unable to apply weight paint at all so i applied so many subdivisions. Now can i dissolve vertices and apply weight paint. your advise would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Crantisz' answer, your topology is stretched a lot on X, thus this stretched weight paint:

[image]

Comment: Ohh okk. Any solution for it

Comment: well, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, maybe restart from scratch with a more regular dimension if you don't need it to be stretched, and also subdivide it less if you don't need so many faces (why so many faces btw?)

Comment: I dont know. At first i was unable to apply weight paint at all so i seaked for some solutions on the internet and got to know that we should apply subdivisions to apply weight paint so i applied so many subdivisions. Now can i dissolve vertices and apply weight paint. your advise would be very helpful.

Comment: what is your project exactly, what kind of object are you working on? you probably don't need so many vertices. If you just want to test the Weight Paint mode, you can do it with a simple plane. Subdivide it a bit if you want to test the different brushes and the different modes

Comment: Even with regular grid you will not have good weight paint, see may answer.

Comment: @ Crantisz, yes you're right

Comment: Actually my project is almost done and i just wanted to add some particles on some parts of the plane. So i was trying to weight paint the plane and all this mess happen.